# Multiplexing with a limited number of pins

Tags: multiplexer, atmega328p

I want to create a 10x20/20x10 grid of LEDs by multiplexing. I will probably use an Atmega328p chip for my project, and I obviously don't see 30+ digital pins. Will any of these methods work to multiplex?

- Multiple chips: maybe I could connect some Atmega8s to the Atmega328 via serial connections. Concerns: multiple chips drain the battery faster. Can the columns and rows be controlled by separate chips, or would that cause problems?
- I2C: is there some way I can use I2C to connect the grid of LEDs to the Atmega?
- Any other ways: I am new to using microprocessors (coming from Arduino), so maybe there is something I am missing? Maybe some kind of processor with lots of digital pins I can connect to the Atmega?

Comment: Yes, any method will work. To all your questions the anwer is yes, expand via another MCU, expand via I2C, or any other method like LED driver chip.

Comment: What kind of LEDs would you use? Simple, color, strips of leds or LEDs matrix?

Comment: How much current does each LED need?

Comment: Multiple processors for more I/Os seems overkill. Shift registers are better: simpler and cheaper. You can also use parallel latches if you want more speed and less flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what your LEDs are so I'm gessing these

[image: general led green]

They don't consume lots of amps so you can use method #1 and #2.

If you are talking about led strips like these #1 and #2 won't work.

[image: led strips]

> Multiple chips: maybe I could connect some Atmega8s to the Atmega328
> via serial connections. Concerns: multiple chips drain the battery
> faster. Can the columns and rows be controlled by separate chips, or
> would that cause problems?

It depends on your programming capabilities but everything is possible.

> I2C: is there some way I can use I2C to
> connect the grid of LEDs to the Atmega?

Yes you absolutly can for exemple there are lots of GPIO expender with I2C for exemple :
[PCF8575](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/xreef/pcf8575-i2c-16-bit-digital-input-output-expander-48a7c6)

> Any other ways: I am new to
> using microprocessors (coming from Arduino), so maybe there is
> something I am missing? Maybe some kind of processor with lots of
> digital pins I can connect to the Atmega?

That would cost way more but you can go for an ATmega2560 or you can add a shift register like this one (that is for high voltage so not your usecase) [32 channel shift register](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/HV5222)

You should search on Youtube / Google for similar projects and get ideas there.

Answer (score 3):

There are some shift-register-based drivers chips *(Sorry, I'm not going to give an example here as it violates the community rules)*.

The idea is to create an A x B LED matrix, where A is the number of rows which are driven by the MCU directly or through a high-side switch (depending on the current/power requirements), and B is the number of columns which are driven by the SR-based drivers.

Here's a principal schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAI49h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each chip is capable of driving **n** LEDs simultaneously (There are chips with n = 4, 8, 16, … in the market). You can send **N** bits (N >= n) to the first chip. It'll take first **n** bits from the bits train then sends the rest (N - n bits) to the next chip. And this chip will take first n bits from this train then sends the rest to the next chip. This goes on until the last chip takes the remaining and there's nothing left to transmit.

Here's the working principle:

```
for each r in rows
{
    prepare_row_pixel_data(r);
    turn_off_all_rows();
    send_row_pixel_data(r); //e.g. 1s and 0s for the current row
    turn_on_row(r);
    wait(muxing_period);
    
    next r;
}
```

With this, you'll need A + x pins, where x is the required communication pins for the chips (generally, not more than 2).

This is basically how dot matrix displays or large LED-based displays work.

Remember that if the current requirements exceed the total driving capability of the MCU then you'll need to use a high-side driver: You can use a chip or build your own driver with a PNP/PMOS.

Answer (score 3):

The question is posed with the assumption of multiplexing with MCU being the only solution. Why bother multiplexing with MCU to begin with, as addressable RGB LEDs are invented and there are plenty of easy solutions.

All it takes is one single data pin on your MCU to connect arbitrary amount of LEDs, 200 being doable.

Failing that, there are chips that are dedicated to driving LED matrices and have I2C or SPI bus as a control interface.

Answer (score 2):

You Atmega328 has plenty of pins, you only need 15 with [Charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) (named after Charles Allen, first used in Maxim's MAX6951 LED driver).

The linked wikipedia article above has a very thorough description of the circuits, advantages and limitations, so I'll only give an outline here.

There are two ways to think about Charlieplexing. One is to consider a connection of N lines in all possible pairs. The other is to consider an otherwise square matrix, with one selected undriven row used to drive a column. This second matrix version is more systematic and much easier to write the software for. Both (necessarily) give rise to the same expression, you can drive N*(N-1) LEDs with N lines.

For your case of 200 LEDs, you would need 15 lines (14x15 = 210), or you could go for broke and use 16 (15x16 = 240). The Atmega328p has 23 I/O.

The 328p I/O is not sufficient to drive a whole column of LEDs, and it may or may not be able to manage a single one. It depends on the brightness you want. As you will be driving through at least a 15:1 multiplex, you may want to crank the LED current up beyond the 20 mA the I/O can manage.

The driving scheme relies on using the three-state ability of the pins.

- A high pin drives the whole column, through the upper follower transistor.
- A three state pin does not drive the corresponding LED
- A low pin drives the LED in the driven column, with current being limited by the resistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4iRx2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is an illustration for how to arrange and drive a 3x2 matrix, obviously the general plan can be extended to any size N x (N-1) matrix.

The LEDs are numbered Drc, for row, column. Note that no LEDs occupy the same row and column, there are no LEDs numbered Dxx.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftCitW.png)</sup>

You can see that if we are driving the first column, Q1 is driven high. The other two row drivers are pulled low, or left high impedance, to light the LEDs in that column.